# help/searching doesn’t mention the `deleted` operator

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, searching, help-center

There’s a boolean operator for the search that’s not mentioned on [the searching help page](https://askubuntu.com/help/searching):

- `deleted:` yes/true/1 returns only posts that have been deleted; the default no/false/0 excludes deleted posts from the search. This operator does only return your own deleted posts regardless of the `user` operator and is useable only by users with the [Access To Moderator Tools](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) privilege.

The above should be added in the “Boolean Operators” subsection.

Comment: Just for a reference, it's mentioned on ["Access To Moderator Tools" privilege](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) (aka 10k rep): "*You also have a new search operator available to find your own deleted posts: `deleted:1`.*" Also, users not having this privilege won't be able to search their own deleted posts with this operator though.

Comment: @AndrewT. nice finding, I included this information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nit-pick: this *isn't* actually a boolean operator...

I've added a separate section at the end detailing who can search deleted posts, and how they may do so:

> #### Deleted Posts (requires $Privilege-ModerationTools reputation)
>
> When you earn [the Access to Moderator Tools](/help/privileges/moderator-tools) privilege, you may search your own deleted posts by using the `deleted:` operator.
>
> - `deleted:1` searches only your deleted posts
> - `deleted:all` searches both deleted and not-deleted posts that you've authored
> - `deleted:0` searches only not-deleted posts that you've authored (effectively the same as `user:me`)
>
> [Site Moderators](/help/site-moderators) may use this operator to search *all* posts on the site, including those owned by other users.

Answer (score 4):

I know this isn't an answer to the question but we can 
see our own *recently* deleted posts from our profile:

1. Open your profile:

   [image]
2. Open the *Activity* tab

   [image]
3. Open the *answers* or *questions* tab

   [image]
4. Scroll down and click `deleted recent answers`

   [image]

Comment: Yes, +1 that is relevant and useful, and also a good thing to point out because everyone can access it afaik. However, it is limited - it only shows recent answers that have been deleted, whereas the search option dessert mentions returns all the searcher's own deleted posts if they have <10k

Comment: @Zanna Re _"the search option dessert mentions returns all the searcher's own deleted posts if they have <10k"_ No. It doesn't. If a user has rep<10k, then the `delete:1` option has no effect. It simply doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, I used the wrong angle bracket in my comment! I meant >10k

Comment: @Zanna I think I read somewhere (unless it's a false memory) that "**recent**" = past 60 days.